# c# how to call onpaint continuously without lag

Tags: c#, overriding, onpaint, paintevent

I am making a custom user control  ,  but when i override `OnPaint()` , it is not call continuously .
This is my code :

```
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:ColoredProgressBar runat=server></{0}:ColoredPorgressBar>")]
    public class ColoredProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {
        public Timer timer;

        public ColoredProgressBar()
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Start();
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        }
        public void timer_Tick(object sender , EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            // Call methods of the System.Drawing.Graphics object.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), ClientRectangle);
            Console.WriteLine("???");
        }
    }
```

i waited 10 seconds , message "???" should continuously show up in my Console , 
bug i only see 12 message show up . i tried `Invalidate(true);` although message show up continuously , the form is very lag .

`e.Graphics.DrawString` is not a very expensive method , right ?

How can i call `OnPaint()`  continuously without lag?

Comment: Well you're not causing the window to repaint anywhere in that code. Perhaps you should do something inside `timer_Tick()`, such as `this.Invalidate()` or `this.Refresh()`...

Comment: This work ! Thank you vary much ! ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in your code works as it should. WinForms is just a framework on top of WinApi and GDI+ so you have to first get some knowledge about windows internal message pump and messages that it sends about which you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx).
As you can see there's a [`WM_PAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx) message that is then used by WinForms to repaint the controls.

Every `OnPaint` event is called after your application receives `WM_PAINT` message. You can of course force this message by using methods like [`Invalidate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx) which will not force painting routine synchronously as stated on msdn page, and you would have to call [`Update()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update(v=vs.110).aspx) after which should be used as :

```
this.Invalidate();
this.Update();
```

Or you can directly call [`Refresh()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) method which will force redraw of your control and all of it's children.